# MAMP Pro 4.3 Apache not starting

Tags: apache, mamp-pro

How to solve the problem "MAMP Pro 4.3 Apache not starting".

- MAMP Pro 4.3
- Using the System Administrator account in Mac
- macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.2 (17C88)
- apache_error.log is empty

`I have already rename _envvars`

Comment: I got the same problem, I will try to investigate and report back here.

Comment: @i.bajrai thank you very much i.bajrai.I am still facing this problems

Comment: @I.bajrai am running into this exact same issue. Have either of you found a solution yet and if so would you mind sharing it?

Comment: @Chris I manage to run apache under "Ports" then run servers as Unix users.

Comment: @i.bajrai  I manage to run apache under "Ports" then run servers as Unix users.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrestling this problem since upgrading from MAMP Pro 4.2.1 to 4.3 and MAMP 4.4. I was able to start Apache with no errors after resetting the Apache templates. You can find this in MAMP Pro "File > Edit Template > Revert all Templates to Default Settings..."

Of course in MAMP Pro this will reset ALL the templates, not just Apache. Perhaps it can be done manually in the filesystem.

Comment: Okay let me try.

Comment: I have encountered this frequently after apple updates that Mamp will misbehave. I can confirm that a template reset usually sorts this out but cannot explain why.